# Making form one column

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

Form is currently two columns, making the UI look awkward given there are just two form fields. I'm looking to make the field just one column given there are only two fields. How can I adjust?

Believe it has something to do with display: flex; but every alternate option I try, does not seem to work

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter:400,500,600,700,800,900');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #FFFFFF !important;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Inter'
}

h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
label,
span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'inter';
}

body,
html,
.App,
#root,
.auth-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  font-family: Inter;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #939599;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Inter;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #494D61;
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.auth-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}

.auth-inner {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 40px 55px 45px 55px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.auth-wrapper .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #FBB381;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.auth-wrapper .form-control {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  border-color: #EBEBEB;
}

.auth-wrapper h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.custom-control-label {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.forgot-password,
.forgot-password a {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #7f7d7d;
  margin: 0;
}

.forgot-password a {
  color: #FBB381;
}

.btn btn-primary btn-block {
  color: #FBB381 !important;
}

.col-left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.col-right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  /* to use css-grid */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  /* creates 2 columns */
  gap: 10px 50px;
  /* creates a gap between the columns and rows */
}

form h3,
form h4,
form p,
form button {
  grid-column: span 2;
  /* lets those elements span both columns */
}

.form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* flexbox is sued to palce the label and input below each other and allows the input to fill out the entrie width */
}

.button {
  background-color: #FBB381;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #FBB381;
  height: 50px;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h4>Sign In</h4>
  <div className="form-group">
    <label>Email address</label>
    <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
  </div>
  <div className="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
  </div>
  <div className="form-group">
    <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" />
      <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customCheck1">Remember me</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" className="button">Login</button>
  <p className="forgot-password text-right">
    Forgot <a href="/">password?</a>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `class` instead of `className` (unless you are using React). Also, you are using a `CSS-grid` which is splitting it into two columns. Change `grid` to `flex` on `form` and use a column flex-direction.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter:400,500,600,700,800,900');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #FFFFFF !important;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Inter'
}

h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
label,
span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'inter';
}

body,
html,
.App,
#root,
.auth-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  font-family: Inter;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #939599;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Inter;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #494D61;
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.auth-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}

.auth-inner {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 40px 55px 45px 55px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.auth-wrapper .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #FBB381;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.auth-wrapper .form-control {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  border-color: #EBEBEB;
}

.auth-wrapper h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.custom-control-label {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.forgot-password,
.forgot-password a {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #7f7d7d;
  margin: 0;
}

.forgot-password a {
  color: #FBB381;
}

.btn btn-primary btn-block {
  color: #FBB381 !important;
}

.col-left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.col-right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  /* creates a gap between the columns and rows */
}

form h3,
form h4,
form p,
form button {
  grid-column: span 2;
  /* lets those elements span both columns */
}

.form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* flexbox is sued to palce the label and input below each other and allows the input to fill out the entrie width */
}

.button {
  background-color: #FBB381;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #FBB381;
  height: 50px;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h4>Sign In</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" />
      <label class="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customCheck1">Remember me</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="button">Login</button>
  <p class="forgot-password text-right">
    Forgot <a href="/">password?</a>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Does not answer the question

Comment: @KirkCode See edits ~ I was confused about what you meant by two columns.

Comment: `className` is correct as he is using React

Comment: @tacoshy I figured, but OP did not specify. Solution still works with `className`

Answer (score 1):

Changes made:

- Change all *ClassName* to *Class*
- Change *form* from:

```
form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 10px 50px;
}
```

to

```
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: You should copy the snippet down and modify it to demonstrate.